# How to add discount for final subtotal in ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using Ubercart in Drupal 7. I need to add discount offer based on price.

For example:

- if total purchase price $100 then 25% discount.
- If total purchase price $200 then 45%.
- and so on.

I used the uc_discount module but it's not working according me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ubercart Simple Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_simple_discount)

This module works with rules, so you can add a condition in rules.
You may not get an 'easy plug and play' module for doing this, but the result you want may be possible with some [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)